# Asana Boards task api integration

Tags: asana

Asana have just released a new boards feature.

Is there any way to get the column where a task belongs through the api?

I don't see any documentation about this field.
When I call the task rest resource there is no data about it:

https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/0000000000/tasks?&opt_expand=(this%7Csubtasks%2B)

```
{
  "data": [
  {
    "id": 214497961570704,
    "created_at": "2016-11-17T07:30:18.834Z",
    "modified_at": "2016-11-17T07:39:13.350Z",
    "name": "Title",
    "notes": "",
    "assignee": null,
    "completed": false,
    "assignee_status": "upcoming",
    "completed_at": null,
    "due_on": null,
    "due_at": null,
    "projects": [
    {
      "id": 11111111111,
      "name": "NAME"
    }
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "workspace": {
      "id": 111111111,
      "name": "work"
    },
    "num_hearts": 0,
    "parent": null,
    "hearted": false,
    "hearts": [],
    "memberships": [
    {
      "project": {
      "id": 213571757473663,
      "name": "PROJECTNAME"
    },
    "section": null
  }
],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Boards API is still under development.  We are excited to hear that you are eager to use it.  If you’re interested in trying it out and helping to shape its implementation, please email us at devrel@asana.com. Note that we are still finalizing the design and some endpoints will change.

Comment: I don't get sections calling that endpoint, the response is empty.
GET https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/213571757473663/sections
{
"data": []
}
Maybe the API is not released yet